# How to pass json data from main report to subreport Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I want to create a report like this
[image]

I have the structure of the tables created, in the page 2 the source data is a JSON with a list of products and its properties.
I want to shows the JSON data into the tables, actually have a subreport with the tables, but don't know how pass the JSON data to the subreport and its fill according to the productList key in JSON data. The report fills from a java class that receives the data from the user.

I don't know how to fill the tables of the page 2, can anyone helps me?

This is my code in Jaspersoft Studio 6.10

Main Report

```
https://app.box.com/s/qhl0158r03g9jowrhofojd6pkodwkojs
```

SubReport

```
https://app.box.com/s/gt5h19qxj1gs5ldghvajd3umx720dwgp
```

Java class (Fill the report)

```
    ...
    JasperReport jr = null;

    //DATA TO THE REPORT
    String nombreCliente = "Caracol Radio LTDA.";
    String contactoCliente = "3694100";
    String nombreUsuario = "David";
    String apellidoUsuario = "Torres";
    String cargoUsuario = "Aux. Administrativo";
    String nombreEmpresaCondicionesComerciales = "BIO BOLSA";
    String tipoCuentaCondicionesComerciales = "Ahorros";
    String bancoCondicionesComerciales = "Davivienda";
    String numeroCuentaCondicionesComerciales = "481670000670";
    String domicilioCondicionesEntrega = "Bogotá";
    String simboloMonedaCondicionesEntrega = "$";
    String embalajeSuperiorCondicionesEntrega = "800.000";
    String impuestoCondicionesEntrega = "iva";
    String domicilioFueraCondicionesEntrega = "iva";
    String capacidadInstaladaOrdenProduccion = "1.000.000";

    String tipoEmpresa = "S.A.S";
    String regimenEmpresa = "Regimen Comun";
    String nitEmpresa = "900.390.537-1";
    String telefonosEmpresa = "Tels: (57) (1) 7137516 EXT 1142 – 7138731 - 2033205 Cel: (57) 300 275 45 51";
    String correoWebEmpresa = "Web: www.biobolsa.com.co   E-mail: pchacon@biobolsa.com.co";
    String direccionEmpresa = "Fábrica CRA 57 NO 45 A – 52 SUR LA SEVILLANA";
    String ciudadEmpresa = "Bogotá D.C, Colombia";

    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parametros.put("NombreCliente", nombreCliente);
    parametros.put("ContactoCliente", contactoCliente);
    parametros.put("NombreUsuario", nombreUsuario);
    parametros.put("ApellidoUsuario", apellidoUsuario);
    parametros.put("CargoUsuario", cargoUsuario);
    parametros.put("TipoEmpresa", tipoEmpresa);
    parametros.put("Regimen", regimenEmpresa);
    parametros.put("Nit", nitEmpresa);
    parametros.put("Telefonos", telefonosEmpresa);
    parametros.put("WebCorreo", correoWebEmpresa);
    parametros.put("Direccion", direccionEmpresa);
    parametros.put("Ciudad", ciudadEmpresa);
    parametros.put("NombreEmpresaCondicionesComerciales", nombreEmpresaCondicionesComerciales);
    parametros.put("TipoCuentaCondicionesComerciales", tipoCuentaCondicionesComerciales);
    parametros.put("BancoCondicionesComerciales", bancoCondicionesComerciales);
    parametros.put("NumeroCuentaCondicionesComerciales", numeroCuentaCondicionesComerciales);
    parametros.put("DomicilioCondicionesEntrega", domicilioCondicionesEntrega);
    parametros.put("SimboloMonedaCondicionesEntrega", simboloMonedaCondicionesEntrega);
    parametros.put("EmbalajeSuperiorCondicionesEntrega", embalajeSuperiorCondicionesEntrega);
    parametros.put("ImpuestoCondicionesEntrega", impuestoCondicionesEntrega);
    parametros.put("DomicilioFueraCondicionesEntrega", domicilioFueraCondicionesEntrega);
    parametros.put("CapacidadInstaladaOrdenProduccion", capacidadInstaladaOrdenProduccion);

    try {
        jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("PATH\\TO\\REPORT\\ReporteBiobolsa.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, parametros, new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, "PATH\\TO\\EXPORT\\PDFBiobolsa.pdf");


        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity("OK.......!!")
                .build();
    } catch (JRException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity("ERROR.......!!")
                .build();
    }
```

JSON data

```
{
"productList": [{
            "productNumber": 1,
            "modelo": "Bolsa Deportiva Plana",
            "tela": "Tafeta",
            "dimensiones": "40x35",
            "destino": "Bog, D.C",
            "accesoriosModelo": [{
                "nombre": "Cordon"
            },{
                "nombre": "Accesorio 2"
            },{
                "nombre": "Accesorio 3"
            }],
            "accesoriosAdicionales": [{
                "nombre": "Bolsillo (30x40)"
            },{
                "nombre": "Accesorio Adicional 2"
            },{
                "nombre": "Accesorio Adicional 3"
            }],
            "estampado": [{
                "nombre": "Cara Frontal – 1 Tinta"
            },{
                "nombre": "Cara Posterior – 1 Tinta"
            },{
                "nombre": "Estampado 3"
            }],
            "observaciones": "Observacion de Prueba",
            "cantidad": 500,
            "vrUnitario": 1200,
            "subTotal": 600000,
            "iva": 50000,
            "total": 650000
        },
        {
            "productNumber": 2,
            "modelo": "Bolsa Deportiva",
            "tela": "Otra",
            "dimensiones": "50x20",
            "destino": "Bog, D.C",
            "accesoriosModelo": [{
                "nombre": "Cremallera"
            },{
                "nombre": "Accesorio 2"
            },{
                "nombre": "Accesorio 3"
            }],
            "accesoriosAdicionales": [{
                "nombre": "Botones"
            },{
                "nombre": "Accesorio Adicional 2"
            },{
                "nombre": "Accesorio Adicional 3"
            }],
            "estampado": [{
                "nombre": "Cara Posterior – 1 Tinta"
            }],
            "observaciones": "Observacion de Prueba",
            "cantidad": 400,
            "vrUnitario": 900,
            "subTotal": 360000,
            "iva": 40000,
            "total": 400000
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you give the JSON data to the report?
If you give the data over a java program via parameters to your MainReport you have to define the parameters in the report. When you want to give the data to your subreport, you have to define the exact same parameter in both reports (sub and main). It is important that you DON'T use the parameter (datasource) you wanne use for your table in another way too. Jasper uses datasources only one time, if you want to use the same datasource for a table and a chart (cause you wanne show the same data in two different ways) you have to give two different datasources with the same data to the report.

Comment: How about a reaktion to my answer? @davids182009